# Android Kotlin Retrofit + SimpleXMLConverter ElementList not parsing correctly

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, retrofit2, simple-framework

I'm trying to parse some podcast xml feeds, but can not get all categories and other multiple fields that have the same name.

Feed example: http://demo3984434.mockable.io/cast

```
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:itunesu="http://www.itunesu.com/feed" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Podcast Title</title>
        <link>http://link.com</link>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <itunes:subtitle>Subtitle!!!</itunes:subtitle>
        <itunes:author>Author Name</itunes:author>
        <media:category scheme="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">Comedy</media:category>
        <media:category scheme="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">Society &amp; Culture</media:category>
        <media:category scheme="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">Games &amp; Hobbies/Video Games</media:category>
        <media:category scheme="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">TV &amp; Film</media:category>
        <media:category scheme="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">Music</media:category>
        <itunes:category text="Comedy"/>
        <itunes:category text="Society &amp; Culture"/>
        <itunes:category text="Games &amp; Hobbies"/>
        <itunes:category text="Video Games"/>
        <itunes:category text="TV &amp; Film"/>
        <itunes:category text="Music"/>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

RSSFeed.kt:

```
@Root(name = "rss", strict = false)
class RSSFeed {

    @field:Element(name = "channel")
    var mFeedChannel: FeedChannel? = null
}
```

FeedChannel.kt

```
@Root(name = "channel", strict = false)
open class FeedChannel {

    @field:Element(name = "title")
    var mTitle: String? = null

    @field:Element(name = "link")
    var mLink: String? = null

    @field:Element(name = "subtitle")
    var mSubtitle: String? = null

    @field:Element(name = "author")
    var mAuthor: String? = null

    @field:ElementList(entry = "category", inline = true)
    var mCategories: List<Category>? = null

    @Root(name = "category", strict = false)
    class Category {

        @field:Element(name = "category")
        var category: String? = null
    }
}
```

But the categories list elements are always null:
[image]

Comment: `var mCategories: List<String>? = null` might work for the first 5 media:category elements

Comment: See how you are saying a category has a category in it in the Category class definition. `<category> <category/> </category>` <- Probably not what you want.

Comment: @DaveThomas Now I get this exception:
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=, inline=true, name=category, required=true, type=void) on field 'mCategories' private java.util.List ....model.FeedChannel.mCategories for class ....model.FeedChannel at line 5

Comment: Looks like it is choking on those elements that have value as an attribute.  Side-note: You can update your question to include information saying you are using org.simpleframework.xml. That will someone familiar with the framework find your question and help you get a solution.

Comment: @DaveThomas I found a solution based in what you said, just changed the annotation field from "name" to "entry" and adding the "type" field

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

Changed the @field:Element fields and used String for instead of another class Category. Thanks to @DaveThomas

```
@Root(name = "channel", strict = false)
class FeedChannel {

    @field:Element(name = "title")
    var mTitle: String? = null

    @field:Element(name = "link")
    var mLink: String? = null

    @field:Element(name = "subtitle")
    var mSubtitle: String? = null

    @field:Element(name = "author")
    var mAuthor: String? = null

    @field:ElementList(entry = "category", type = String::class, inline = true)
    var mCategories: List<String>? = null

}
```

Comment: `How we can get attribute like: @Path("enclosure") @param:Attribute(name = "url") var url: String = "", I am getting error: "Caused by: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ConstructorException: Parameter 'enclosure[1]/@url' does not have a match in class`